# How to check whether a file is empty or not

Tags: python, file, file-length

I have a text file. How can I check whether it's empty or not?

Answer (score 512, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat("file").st_size == 0
True
```

Comment: that's fine too. but i don't want to import stat. Its short and sweet enough and the size position in the returned list is not going to change anytime soon.

Comment: Note that the file types work for json, too. Sometimes, json.load() for empty file doesn't work and this provides a good way to handle that case

Comment: what if the file only contain new line / empty? wrong answer!

Comment: @lone_coder It's not actually empty if it has a newline character in it.

Comment: @sappjw but the size still indicates zero. that's why this is wrong

Comment: @lone_coder this gives me `1`: `echo -en '\n' >/tmp/nl; python -c 'import os; print(os.stat("/tmp/nl").st_size)'`

Comment: sometimes file's size is 4Kib even its empty

Comment: What is bad is opening the file, reading it using `read()` and check for a length of zero?

Comment: @Orb Imagine file that can have size of 170GB.

Answer (score 160):

```
import os    
os.path.getsize(fullpathhere) > 0
```

Comment: For safety you may need to catch `OSError` and return False.

Comment: What is the difference/advantage using this vs os.state('file').st_size?

Comment: Looks like the two are the same under the hood: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962257/1397061

Comment: This returns 20 even the file is empty

Comment: @alper 20 is the size of a gzipped empty file. If your file was truly empty, with `ls -l` (or `dir` on windows) reporting a size of 0, `os.path.getsize()` should also return 0.

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 93):

Both `getsize()` and `stat()` will throw an exception if the file does not exist. This function will return True/False - usually without throwing:

```
import os
def is_non_zero_file(fpath):  
    return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.path.getsize(fpath) > 0
```

There is a race condition because the file may be removed between the calls to os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.path.getsize(fpath), in which case the proposed function will still raise an exception

Comment: Definitely like using ``os.path.getsize()``

Comment: There is a race condition because the file may be removed between the calls to `os.path.isfile(fpath)` and `os.path.getsize(fpath)`, in which case the proposed function will raise an exception.

Comment: Better to try and catch the `OSError` instead, like proposed [in another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/python-how-to-check-file-empty-or-not/15924160#comment2503155_2507819).

Comment: Also need to catch `TypeError` which will be raised in the event that the input fpath is `None`.

Answer (score 57):

If you are using Python 3 with `pathlib` you can access [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) information using the [`Path.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) method, which has the attribute `st_size` (file size in bytes):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> mypath = Path("path/to/my/file")
>>> mypath.stat().st_size == 0 # True if empty
```

Answer (score 39):

If for some reason you already had the file open, you could try this:

```
>>> with open('New Text Document.txt') as my_file:
...     # I already have file open at this point.. now what?
...     my_file.seek(0) # Ensure you're at the start of the file..
...     first_char = my_file.read(1) # Get the first character
...     if not first_char:
...         print "file is empty" # The first character is the empty string..
...     else:
...         my_file.seek(0) # The first character wasn't empty. Return to the start of the file.
...         # Use file now
...
file is empty
```

Comment: exactly the scenario which i had.. after checking the file, the pointer skipped the first char and i was confused on the final output.... thanks for this...

Answer (score 17):

if you have the file object, then

```
>>> import os
>>> with open('new_file.txt') as my_file:
...     my_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # go to end of file
...     if my_file.tell(): # if current position is truish (i.e != 0)
...         my_file.seek(0) # rewind the file for later use 
...     else:
...         print "file is empty"
... 
file is empty
```

Comment: This answer is should have more votes because it actually checks whether the file has any contents at all.

Comment: @amanb In which cases it will report something different than `os.stat("file").st_size == 0`?

Answer (score 12):

Combining [ghostdog74's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507871/17772) and the comments:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('c:/pagefile.sys').st_size==0
False
```

`False` means a non-empty file.

So let's write a function:

```
import os

def file_is_empty(path):
    return os.stat(path).st_size==0
```

Answer (score 4):

An important gotcha: a **compressed empty file** will appear to be non-zero when tested with `getsize()` or `stat()` functions:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getsize('empty-file.txt.gz')
35
>>> os.stat("empty-file.txt.gz").st_size == 0
False

$ gzip -cd empty-file.txt.gz | wc
0 0 0
```

So you should check whether the file to be tested is compressed (e.g. examine the filename suffix) and if so, either bail or uncompress it to a temporary location, test the uncompressed file, and then delete it when done.

**Better way to test size of compressed files**: read it directly using [the appropriate compression module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html). You would only need to read the first line of the file, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554346/138325).

Comment: a nice gotcha you introduced here!

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not defined what an empty file is: Some might also consider a file with just blank lines as an empty file. So if you want to check if your file **contains only blank lines (any white space character, '\r', '\n', '\t')**, you can follow the example below:

**Python 3**

```py
import re

def whitespace_only(file):
    content = open(file, 'r').read()
    if re.search(r'^\s*$', content):
        return True
```

Explanation: the example above uses a regular expression (regex) to match the content (`content`) of the file.

Specifically: for a regex of: `^\s*$` as a whole means if the file contains only blank lines and/or blank spaces.

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\s` matches any white space character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: I downvoted because 1- there’s no need to define an empty file: it’s a file with no content. A file that contains blank lines is not empty. 2- this reads the whole file in memory.

Comment: I think this is BAD answer as well. Because it works only for really blank files. But as soon as file is not blank you could face with many errors, one of them `UnicodeDecodeError`. Be careful to use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

An easy simple method I used recently is this:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w+')

f.seek(0) #Unecessary but important if file was manipulated before reading
if f.read() == '':
    print("no data found")
else:
    print("Data present in file")
```

You can use the above as inspiration for your desired uses (keeping in mind I am pretty new to file handling this seemed to suit my desired use in a program I was writing).

Comment: seek(0) saves my day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a CSV file is empty or
not, try this:

```
with open('file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames = ['user_name', 'user_age', 'user_email', 'user_gender', 'user_type', 'user_check'])
    if os.stat('file.csv').st_size > 0:
        pass
    else:
        csv_writer.writeheader()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way not using the `os` library:

```
with open('filename') as myfile:
    if len(myfile.readlines()):
        print("It's not empty")
```