# Correct way to check for empty or missing file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check both whether a file exists and, if it does, if it is empty.

If the file doesn't exist, I want to exit the program with an error message.

If the file is empty I want to exit with a different error message.

Otherwise I want to continue.

I've been reading about using Try: Except: but I'm not sure how to structure the code 'Pythonically' to achieve what I'm after?

---

Thank you for all your responses, I went with the following code:

```
try:
    if os.stat(URLFilePath + URLFile).st_size > 0:
        print "Processing..."
    else:
        print "Empty URL file ... exiting"
        sys.exit()
except OSError:
    print "URL file missing ... exiting"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the program is loading URLs from the file I'm checking, doing stuff with them, then zeroing out the file using `open(URLFile, 'w').close()`.  I'm going to run the program every few minutes so I want it to exit if no new URLs have been added in the meantime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python how to check file empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/python-how-to-check-file-empty-or-not)

Comment: Using exceptions for foreseeable and avoidable errors is lazy. Check if the file exists, and if it does, then check its size.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd use [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) here:

```
try:
    if os.stat(filename).st_size > 0:
       print "All good"
    else:
       print "empty file"
except OSError:
    print "No file"
```

Comment: This is IMO the best solution.

Comment: what about zero byte files?

Comment: @shookees -- Forgive my ignorance, but how is a zero byte file different from an empty file?

Comment: @TheRogueWolf -- Thanks for catching that.  Too early to code apparently :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
try:
    myfile = open(filename)
except IOError:  # FileNotFoundError in Python 3
    print "File not found: {}".format(filename)
    sys.exit()

contents = myfile.read()
myfile.close()

if not contents:
    print "File is empty!"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Is `FileNotFoundError` a thing?  (it isn't for me with python2.7 -- That just raises a `NameError`)  For me it's an `IOError`.  Also, I would discourage reading the entire file (what if the user accidentally provides a file which is 8 Gb?)  I think you can get the empty/non-empty info from `os.stat`.

Comment: @mgilson: Right; I tested `open("blargh")` in Python 3 and had expected the exception also to be present in Python 2. So my previous version was actually correct :)

Comment: Nice, I hadn't realized that they subclassed IOError and created FileNotFoundError in py3k.  cool.

Answer (score 1):

[os.path.exists](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and other functions in os.path.

As for reading,

you want something like

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
    with open(path) as fi:
        if not fi.read(3):  #avoid reading entire file.
             print "File is empty"
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `if os.path.exists(path):`, otherwise this code is trying to open a file that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import sys

try:
    s = os.stat(filename)
    if s.st_size == 0:
        print "The file {} is empty".format(filename)
        sys.exit(1)
except OSError as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if file.tell() == 0:
    print("File is empty!")
else: print("File is not empty")
```