# os.path.getsize(path) or os.stat

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is different between `os.path.getsize(path)` and `os.stat`? which one is best to used in python 3? and when do we use them? and why we have two same solution?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962166/python-os-statfile-name-st-size-versus-os-path-getsizefile-name) answer but I couldn't understand what this quote means:

> From this, it seems pretty clear that there is no reason to expect the two approaches to behave differently (except perhaps due to the different structures of the loops in your code)

specifically why we have two approach and what is there different?

Comment: You can use `strace` program, if you on linux and compare output.

Comment: Documentation says: `os.path.getsize?
Signature: os.path.getsize(filename)
Docstring: Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat().
File:      /usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py
Type:      function
` So, os.path.getsize(path) is only wrapper above `os.stat()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stat` is a POSIX system call (available on Linux, Unix and even Windows) which returns a bunch of information (size, type, protection bits...)

Python has to call it at some point to get the size ([and it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962166/python-os-statfile-name-st-size-versus-os-path-getsizefile-name)), but there's no system call to get *only* the size.

So they're the same performance-wise (maybe faster with `stat` but that's only 1 more function call so not I/O related). It's just that `os.path.getsize` is simpler to write.

that said, to be able to call `os.path.getsize` you have to make sure that the path is actually a *file*. When called on a directory, `getsize` returns some value (tested on Windows) which is probably related to the size of the node, so you have to use `os.path.isfile` first: another call to `os.stat`.

In the end, if you want to maximize performance, you have to use `os.stat`, check infos to see if path is a file, then use the `st_size` information. That way you're calling `stat` only once.

If you're using `os.walk` to scan the directory, you're exposed to more hidden `stat` calls, so look into `os.scandir` (Python 3.5).

Related:

- [Faster way to find large files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144952/faster-way-to-find-large-files-with-python/46145070#46145070)
- [Python os.stat(file_name).st_size versus os.path.getsize(file_name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962166/python-os-statfile-name-st-size-versus-os-path-getsizefile-name) looks like a duplicate but the question (and answer) is different

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are linking to shows that the one calls the other:

```
def getsize(filename):
    """Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
```

so fundamentally, both functions are using `os.stat`.

Why? probably because they had similar needs in two different packages, `path` and `stat`, and didn't want to duplicate code.