# Writing headers in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a program which will run on a cron job and write the output to a CSV file.

I get it to write correctly but I would like to make the program write headers on the first row when the file is created.  Is there a way of the program checking if there are any rows in the CSV file and, if not, writing the headers.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python how to check file empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/python-how-to-check-file-empty-or-not)

Comment: I will try seeing if a file is empty I hadn't though of that and I have looked about and tried to write the code if there where no lines present but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a flag:

```
headers_written = False
```

then when writing rows:

```
if not headers_written:
    writer.writerow(headers)
    headers_written = True

writer.writerow(somerow)
```

You'd actually postpone creating the writer until you are sure you have stuff to write:

```
writer = None

# ...

if not writer:
    writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'wb'))
    writer.writerow(headers)

writer.writerow(somerow)
```