# How to check if csv file is empty using pandas in python?

Tags: python, csv, path

I have many CSV files in a particular folder. I want to check if each file among them is empty, and if yes, print its name.

Files:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Expected output:

```
Empty file :- 
file2.csv
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-empty-or-not

Comment: This is a basic Python question, not specifically pandas

Answer (score 4):

This is how you do it but not with pandas.

```py
for file in file_list:
    if os.stat(file).st_size != 0:
        # df = pd.read_csv(file)
        # do your stuf
```

An other example

```py
import os
if os.stat(file).st_size == 0:
    do something
```

But if you have to do it with pandas that's the right way

```py
for file in file_list:
    try:
        # do your stuff
    except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:
        print "Found empty file : {file}".format(file=file)
```

The code in all examples is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the python os library. You don't need to pandas.

For example:

```
import os

os.path.getsize('yourfile.csv')
```

If file size equal to 0, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.stat("file").st_size == 0
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide an answer, it is generally discouraged on StackOverflow to leave code only answers. Please explain why this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors. Thanks!