# Check if text file is empty

Tags: python

It's a script to move a file to another directory.
How can I implement a checker, that checks if 'LiveryPath.txt' and 'OutputPath.txt' is empty?

````
import shutil
import ctypes
import time

with open("LiveryPath.txt","r") as f:
    Livery = f.read()

with open("Output.txt","r") as g:
    Output = g.read()

root_src_dir = Livery
root_dst_dir = Output


for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            if os.path.samefile(src_file, dst_file):
                continue
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
time.sleep(3)
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your Livery is now installed!", "Success!", 64) ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a file is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-empty-or-not)

Comment: @DSilveiro Not completly. Where should I implement the "If-else?" above the txt file readings or under it? Could you show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.read()` and `g.read()` return the content of your 2 files.
So you just have to check if `f.read()` and `g.read()` are empty, i.e if they are equal to `''`.

Here is an example code:

```py
with open('file.txt') as file:
    content = file.read()
    if content == '':
        print(f'the file {file.name} is empty.')
    else:
        print(f'the file {file.name} is not empty. Here is its content:\n{content}')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
import os


if (os.stat('LiveryPath.txt').st_size == 0) and (os.stat('OutputPath.txt').st_size == 0):
   # do something
```

Comment: added ' for string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the file is empty or not, the size of the file can be checked. There can be couple of more options as well but this one is quite handy.

To achieve it the os utility can be used.

Example implementation

```
import os

def size_checker(filename):
    if os.stat(filename).st_size:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Happy Coding!