# How to concatenate a list of csv files (including empty ones) using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I have a list of .csv files stored in a local folder and I'm trying to concatenate them into one single dataframe.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = r'C:\Users\_M92\Desktop\myFolder'

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder, f), delimiter=';') for f in os.listdir(folder)])
display(df)
```

Only one problem, it happens that one of the files is sometimes empty (0 cols, 0 rows) and in this case, pandas is throwing an `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` in line 6.

Do you have any suggestions how to bypass the empty csv file ?
And why not how to concatenate csv files  in a more efficient/simplest way.

Ideally, I would also like to add a column (to the dataframe df) to carry the name of each .csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would filter the files for content first, then merge them using the basic try-except.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = r'C:\Users\_M92\Desktop\myFolder'
data = []

for f in os.listdir(folder):
   try:
      temp = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder, f), delimiter=';')
      # adding original filename column as per request
      temp['origin'] = f
      data.append(temp)
   except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
      continue

df = pd.concat(data)

display(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Wonhyeong Seo, your code works fine. Thank you so much. Did you see the second part of my post ? I would like to add a column to `df` with the name of each .csv file. Is there a way to make that happen ?

Comment: @L'Artiste Hello! Glad that it worked! I added the column part just now! May you please check in with the `temp['origin'] = f`?

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for your interesting question! I had a lot of fun researching it up :D

Answer (score 3):

You can [check if a file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-empty-or-not) with:

```
import os

os.stat(FILE_PATH).st_size == 0
```

In your use case:

```
import os

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder, f), delimiter=';') \
    for f in os.listdir(folder) \
    if os.stat(os.path.join(folder, f)).st_size != 0
])
```

Comment: Hi @ASGM, Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`.