# How to read in entire folder of csv's and skip items that do not have any columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using the below method to read in entire folder of csv's.  These csv's are dropped in a folder every day and reflect activity that has occurred.  When no activity occurs the csv is blank and still has a size of 1KB.  How can I use this script to skip empty files that still have a file size? Currently I get the error:

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Current code:

```
os.chdir('file_path')
file_extension = '.csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f"*{file_extension}")]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(t) for t in all_filenames], ignore_index=True,sort=False,axis=0)
```

Comment: Michael, do the .csv files contain a header row?  Does each row have multiple columns of data?

Comment: Like what @dtadams79 is getting at, what does an empty file look like? Please edit your post and include a sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can always handle the exception and generate a list of dataframes that you will feed into the concat function. There's probably a way to write this as an oneliner which I don't know. So here's the long version:

```
os.chdir('file_path')
file_extension = '.csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f"*{file_extension}")]

all_dataframes = []
for t in all_filenames:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(t)
        all_dataframes.append(df)
    except pd.io.common.EmptyDataError:
        print("empty csv encountered")
        # if for some reason you would prefer an empty dataframe
        #df = pd.DataFrame()
        #all_dataframes.append(df)

df = pd.concat(all_dataframes, ignore_index=True,sort=False,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer for [How to check whether a file is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507871/246801), we can know if a file is truly empty and just ignore it.

I assume your files look like this:

```
file1.csv
=========
Col1,Col2
a,1
b,2

file2.csv
=========

file3.csv
=========
Col1,Col2
c,3
d,4
```

file2.csv is blank, and does not have headers, otherwise Pandas would not throw the "No columns to parse from file" exception.

```py
import glob
import os

import pandas as pd

file_extension = ".csv"

all_filenames = []
for csv_file in glob.glob(f"*{file_extension}"):
    if os.stat(csv_file).st_size == 0:
        continue
    all_filenames.append(csv_file)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(t) for t in all_filenames], ignore_index=True, sort=False, axis=0)
```

and I get:

```
  Col1  Col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    c     3
3    d     4
```